# Is Possible to embed OpenCV lib into my DLL (develope in Visual C++ )

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, embed, integrate

I have developed my Visual C++ project and release it as DLL, The project uses several open CV functions. My question is "how to integrate(embed) the OpenCV lib into my DLL (create a standalone DLL that contains OpenCV lib inside)?", I want to let users use my dll without install OpenCV or include any OpenCV dll or lib in the other machine.Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Build opencv as static library (Never tested) or deploy all using opencv dll depencies.